# Get JSON Array Value in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
    "start":{
        "lat":14.6687522,
        "lng":120.96757580000008
    },"end":{ 
        "lat":14.6535607,
        "lng":120.98200010000005
    },"waypoints":[
        [
            14.6655377,
            120.98068660000001
        ]
    ]
}
```

I'm using JSON.NET and using the code to get the start's latitude value:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(route);
origin_lat = data["start"].First["lat"].ToString();
```

but I'm receiving an error: `Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Take out `.First` and try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data["start"]` is an object not an array. Try

```
data["start"]["lat"]
```

Comment: Actually tried my code again and matches yours. Thank you!